# Simplification of logic circuit using algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

The following is the logic circuit:

[image]

I have to simplify the following:

(((AB)')'+(B+C)+(AB)'(B+C)')C

=(AB+B+C+(A'+B')(B'C'))C

=(B+C+A'B'C'+B'C')C

=BC+C+A'B'C+B'C

=C+A'BC'+B'C

Comment: One quick way to check, to yourself, whether it's correct is to do a truth table.

Comment: How did you reach the second line? Where did $ABC$ come into the picture?

Comment: Assuming the last line is correct, then you can simplify this to AC+B'C. But your second line does not look correct .. unless you miswrote the very starting expression.

Comment: I made some changes

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3181419/14578, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/431615/31097.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you got from the circuit is not correct. It should be:

$(((AB)')'(B +C)+ (AB)'(B+C)')C$

By Double Negation and DeMorgan that gives you :

$(AB(B+C)+ (A'+B')B'C')C$

The $B$ absorbs the $B+C$, while the $B'$ absorbs to $A'+B'$:

$(AB+B'C')C$

Distribution:

$ABC+B'C'C$

And since the last term is $0$, you are left with:

$ABC$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful!

Comment: @JarvisFerns you're welcome! :)